# Why didn't Stack Overflow notify me for all the answers on my question?

Tags: bug, notifications

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, and later when I checked my account I didn't have any inbox messages about any answers or comments.

After some time I opened the question to see if it got any downvotes and how many views I got. Then I found an answer to my question is there and it got an upvote.

So I recheck my inbox, and I don't have any related to this question. Then I commented on the answer and someone else replied for me and I got a new message for that.

**Here is the screen shot of my inbox.**

[image]

And when I clicked all messages:

[image]

And my question is: *[Textbox enter key alternative for mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700510/textbox-enter-key-alternative-for-mobile-device)*

Why is it like this? Is this a bug of Stack Overflow or is this my problem?

Comment: I think there is some problem with my account, I didn't even get niotification about the upvote just got in this post, [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY2vD.png)

Comment: Votes on meta have no impact on reputation so you don't get notification for those. However you should get a message when an answer is posted to one of your questions so what you reported might be a bug.

Comment: ohh.. thank you for clearing that

Comment: Did you get a notification for my comment? Or was it just for the answer that it was missing?

Comment: yes I got the notification for your comment, and all answers to my other questions, I got notified

Comment: Could be a glitch then, maybe something a site developer can dig into.

Comment: The post owner deleted his post immediately after posting it.  And later undeleted it again, I don't think you get a notification for that.  Not exactly a glitch, but a glitchy outcome.

Comment: If Hans is right, you *did* get a notification...but it was removed/suppressed when the answer was deleted (and as you hadn't been online between those two events, you never saw it, this is this is [status-by-design]). When it was later *undeleted* no new notification is generated (this is [status-by-design]). The unfortunate outcome is that you had no idea it was ever there to begin with.

Comment: @Draco18s Seems to me like a very bad design, IMO notifying after every undelete makes much more sense.

Comment: Can one undelete without seeing the updated content?

Comment: @Oleg I agree that it might be worth notifying people of undeleted content.  All I was saying is, it is probably by design that it doesn't (I originally used "this is probably [status-by-design]" and later redacted the word for simplicity).

Comment: @Oleg: "*IMO notifying after every undelete makes much more sense.*" That would make it easy to really annoy people by pinging them constantly through deletes/undeletes. I understand the idea, but I would say that it makes it too easy to cause mischief.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, that can happen. It's already possible to do something similar by accepting and unaccepting an answer (someone did it dozens of times to one of my answers once and it was quite annoying) revamping the notifications system and making it much more configurable can solve this but I'm not counting on this to happen in the near future.

Answer (score 16):

This was by design, and in my opinion the issue of receiving no notification is the fault of the answerer.

It would be easy to blame caching, but it isn't quite caching's fault *this* time. The answerer posted their answer, and then *19 seconds* later deleted it. I am not sure how fast the observer is for notifications, it is entirely likely that this time window was simply too small for for a notification to be triggered.

When the user then decided to undelete their answer, it did not trigger a notification to be issued, as this event does not seem to be tied into notifications. This is by design, and if you would like to address that aspect of this situation, I would suggest posting a separate feature request.

tl;dr; Don't delete then undelete your answer right after posting it if you want anyone to see it.

Comment: `tl;dr; Don't delete then undelete your answer right after posting it if you want anyone to see it.` is a pointless comment as the OP is the question creator, not the one who answered. I get your explanation but this reads like it's aimed at the OP, which it isn't

Comment: @DarrenSweeney for what it's worth, I didn't read it like that at all. The rest of Travis' answer makes it obvious that they're blaming the answerer.

Comment: I've done this. I've posted an answer, realized it needed more details or there would be downvotes, so deleted the answer to reprevent downvotes, edited off line (since SO won't let you edit until you undelete), then finally posted a better answer. The questioner should get notified period. I'd argue the questioner should also be notified when there are edits (or significant edits) since that info could be invaluable to them (as in, hey I found out my answer had security risks and fixed it)

Comment: I'm also going to suggest this is not the fault of the answerer. The answerer shouldn't have to somehow devine the poor design of SO's notification system. This *design* (if it was designed and not just a bug) works against SO's stated goals

Comment: This is a bad design, that creates unnecessary venue for spam and covert vandalism (it may be hard to abuse this specific case, but there are probably similar places, where that can be exploited). Each change in database should have an associated flag, indicating whether or not it has successfully delivered notifications. If the question gets undeleted, it should generate the appropriate notifications unless previously delivered.

Comment: @gman It is perfectly possible to edit questions while deleted. In fact, I once edited someone else's deleted message by mistake, when I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @Mr.Lister, It is not possible (or didn't used to be possible) to edit **answers** while deleted. No "edit" button appeared. You had to first click "undelete" for the "edit" button to appear. That may have changed since I last needed to do it.

Comment: @gman - It was designed to prevent abuse. Otherwise everyone would post some garbage, delete it, edit it into an answer, and have it look like it was posted prior to anyone else. Or at least, during the height of the fastest answer time frame that is where it came from. I understand that at times it may be prudent to actually do this, I have before as well (although from thousands of answers only a handful of times).

Comment: it's now possible to edit your answer while deleted. Useful when you realize that your answer is plain wrong, delete it, fix it, undelete it, to avoid downvotes in the meanwhile. I never thought it could be used to enter garbage & beat the other answerers

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - If all of our users were of your caliber there wouldn't be the need for any of the systems in place to prevent abuse.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm going to screenshot this comment of yours and put it as a desktop background image :)